# Getting No tests to run on executing pom.xml as maven test but on executing testng.xml its working fine

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, testng, pom.xml

**Getting No tests to run on executing pom.xml as maven test, but on executing testng.xml its working fine.**

**pom.xml - tried including Test case names as well as removing them . nothing is working**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>webAutomation</groupId>
  <artifactId>webAutomation</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version> 2.14.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <suiteXMLFiles>
            <suiteXMLFile>testng.xml</suiteXMLFile>
        </suiteXMLFiles>
         <configuration>
            <includes>
            <include>ocs_TestCase.TC_001.java</include>
            <include>ocs_TestCase.TC01_OCS_Search.java</include>
             </includes>
          </configuration>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

**used Testng.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="ocs_TestCase.TC001"/>
        <class name="ocs_TestCase.TC01_OCS_Search"/>
     </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

**Console log on executing pom.xml as maven test**

```
   [INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.14.1:test (default-test) @ webAutomation ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.851 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-02-10T17:17:39+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/220M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Did you run POM xml as Maven test or Maven Install ?

Comment: as Maven Test only